# Extending a smooth map from a compact subset to the whole manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$, $N$ be two smooth manifolds (Hausdorff and second-countable). Suppose $K \subset U \subset M$, where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open in $M$. If $f: U \rightarrow N$ is a smooth map, is there a smooth map $\tilde{f}:M \rightarrow N$ such that $\tilde{f} = f$ on a neighbourhood of $K$?

I know that it is true when $K$ is a single point or $N = \mathbb{R}^n$. But in general, I don't know if it can be figured out by partition of unity. (I assume that $M$ and $N$ have no boundaries. But I guess the case with boundary is similar.)

Comment: Hint: use partition of unity subordinate to a (finite) open cover of $K \subset U$.

Comment: @Didier But when $N$ is just a manifold, we cannot add the values of the maps as in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And if we use Whitney embedding theorem to put $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, the subset $N$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ might not be convex. Still we cannot add the values of function on each piece by partition of unity.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question

Comment: @Didier Hi, I just find that this is false in general. If we consider $M = \mathbb{R}$, $N = \mathbb{R} \times\{0,1\}$ with $K = \{0,1\}$ and $f(0) = (0,0), f(1) = (0,1)$, then it is impossible to extend $f$ to the whole $\mathbb{R}$. Because $f(\mathbb{R})$ should be connected while $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ lies in different components of $N$.

Comment: Sure, the question makes sense only if $N$ is connected.

Comment: The result is false even though $M$ and $N$ are assumed connected. A counter example is given by $M = \Bbb R^2$, $N = S^1$, $K = S^1 \subset M$, and $f=id_{S^1}$.

Comment: Cool! No retraction from $B^2$ to $S^1$ ! Thank U !!!

Comment: @Didier This should be an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M= \Bbb C$, $U = \{z \in \Bbb C \mid \frac{1}{2}<|z|<2\}$, $K = N = S^1$, and $f \colon U \to N$ defined by $f(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$.
Then $f$ is smooth.
However, $f$ does not even admit a continuous extension to $\Bbb C$: otherwise, it would induce a retraction of $D = \{z \in \Bbb C \mid |z| \leq 1\}$ to $\partial D = S^1$, which is known to be impossible.